# Upstart services work in SSH session, but not in local terminal session

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, upstart, services

If I open a local terminal, and attempt to start an upstart service I get this error:

```
service rsync status
status: Unknown job: rsync
```

But if I SSH in as the same user, it works fine:

```
service rsync status
rsync start/running, process 965
```

Can anyone suggest why the behaviour is different for a local user and a user logged in via SSH?  I assume it must be a problem with my .bashrc or similar, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

**More details:**

Ubuntu 14.04 running on VirtualBox under OS X.

The same symptoms occur if I use sudo.

The same symptoms occur if I try different services.

The same symptoms occur after reboot.

The same symptoms occur for 'service status', 'service start' and 'service stop'.

The failure seems to be in *finding* the service, so I don't think the .conf syntax is the issue.  If I list all the services, I get a very different results:

Local terminal session:

```
initctl list | wc -l
37
```

SSH session (as the same user):

```
initctl list | wc -l
109
```

**Update**

Following suggestions from @muru, I have found a fix/hack.  I've added this to the end of my .bashrc:

```
unset UPSTART_SESSION
```

That feels a bit dirty, and I can't find where that variable is being set in the first place, but it has solved the problem.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What's the output of `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR $UPSTART_SESSION`? The usual is for user jobs not being detected in SSH, the opposite is going on here.

Comment: @muru : in a local terminal, I have `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR $UPSTART_SESSION` => `/run/user/1000 unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1812`.  In the SSH session, `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR $UPSTART_SESSION` => `/run/user/1000`.  I'm afraid that means nothing to me...